# Image source not found in broken links checker AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, express

I need to improve my website's SEO. I am working on an AngularJs Multiple pages application and I have a problem that Angularjs render variables in HTML template we cannot see variable's value in the page source 
Like in my page source I am seeing this

```
<div class="counter_img"><img src="{{counterImage}}" alt=""></div>
```

and it is appearing in broken link checker as 404, I am checking broken links through **Xenu Broken Links Checker**.

I need to see its value in my page source like

```
<div class="counter_img"><img src="/dir/image.png" alt=""></div>
```

I found an API ([Prerender.io](https://prerender.io/)) but it's paid. Would anyone tell me another way to do that - how can I improve my website's SEO?

Answer (score 0):

Template Engines like Angularjs is not good for SEO. you should use prerender.io if your application doesn't contain many pages.

Comment: I used it but still, my issue is the same. couldn't solve it by using prerender.io